# How to cast implementation instance to interface without specifying generic argument (the implementation knows it)?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, .net-assembly, activator

I have an interface:

```
public interface IA<T>
{
     T fce1(float[] data);
     byte[] fce2(T arg);        
}
```

and I have its implementation which specifies certain T (so the implementation do not need anything else):

```
public class A : IA<float>
{
   public float fce1(float[] data)
   {
       return 1f;//data processing
   }

   public byte[] fce2(float arg)
   {
       return BitConverter.GetBytes(arg);//some kind of serialization
   }        
}
```

Class A is in a.dll and I want to get it and call the fce2(fce1()) (so there should be no uknown argument or type. I want to do something following:

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes("a.dll") 
var assembly = Assembly.Load(data);
var expTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

foreach (var d in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
     var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(d);
     if (obj is IA)
     {
          var kernel = obj as IA;
          kernel.fce2(fce1());
     }
}
```

The purpose is to run fce1 as one Task later and fce2 as a second Task when fce1 provides result (this is simplyfied situation).

I tried this with .NET 4.7

I know it could be done to return the object from fce1 and then cast inside fce2 the object to desired type and process it? But is this the only way? I want to avoid casting.

Comment: "_I want to avoid casting_" - Why? Anyway, you could easily achieve this with Reflection which would allow you to dynamically invoke the method without explicitly knowing the type at compile time

Comment: Is fc1() being called on the same object as fc2()? `fce2(fce1(float[]))` returns `byte[]`. It's not generic. Write a non-generic base interface with a method `byte[] fc2fc1(float[])`. Cast the new instance to that. Or did you mean for `T fce1(float[] data);` to be `T fce1(T[] data);`?

Comment: @Martin I also found a way to use the dynamic type, it is also a way. But the performance is low for both - Reflection and Dynamic.

Comment: @EdPlunkett the reason I want both methods split in two is the balance the CPU load. Imagine the float[] input array in fce1 is e.g. 6M of Length and it is incoming each second...The fce1 should process the data and fce2 serialize the results. The serialization could be done independently, but the next float[] packet could be processed only after the previous was processed (because the incoming float[] data are just a chunk in continuous time series)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the dynamic type, the methods invocation could be made (only the first call takes a long time, then it is quite efficient.

```
float[] testingPacket = new float[6250000];
dynamic instance = null;

foreach (var d in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    instance = Activator.CreateInstance(d);
}
int L = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < L; ++i)
{
    dynamic result1 = instance.fce1(testingPacket);
    byte[] buffer = instance.fce2(result1) as byte[];
}
```

The higher the L is the duration period of the for cycle is closer to the duration of object casting and direct declaration using as IA. Thx.